# Как вывести значение переменной в объекте массива (JS)?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Как вывести на экран содержимое переменной  `name`  у **всех** объектов массива?

`arr=[{name:'Black', id:11},{name:'Red',id:12}];`

Answer (score 1):

Немного не понятно что значит вывести на экран. Например так вывести в консоль:

```
arr=[{name:'Black', id:11},{name:'Red',id:12}];
arr.forEach(el => console.log(el.name));
```

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю правильно ли я тебя понял

```
function array(arr) {
    return arr.map(item => {
        alert(item.name)
    })
}

arr=[{name:'Black', id:11},{name:'Red',id:12}]; 
console.log(array(arr))
```

Comment: Зачем второй console.log?

Comment: Для проверки, чтобы посмотреть что будет возвращать функция array

Comment: `alert( arr.map(obj => obj.name) );`